# Update state with value from a list of objects

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a class:

```
struct ClubLength: Identifiable, Decodable, Hashable {
    var id: Int
    var clubName: String
    var distance: Int
}
```

And a picker that fetches the values from a list of `[ClubLength]`:

```
Picker("Club", selection: $clubName) {
    ForEach(clubLengths, id: \.self) {
        Text($0.clubName)
    }
}
.onChange(of: clubName) { _ in
    updateDistance()
}
```

What I wan't to happen when a user selects a new club is change another State variable based on the `ClubLength.distance` value of that club.

I have tried doing by looping over the list of `ClubLength` until `ClubLength.clubName == clubName` but then I get an error: `No exact matches in reference to static method 'buildExpression'`

```
func updateDistance() {
    ForEach(clubLengths, id: \.self) {
        if ($0.clubName == clubName) {
            self.distance = $0.distance
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure there is a much better way to do this but I am having a hard time finding the answer.

Comment: `ForEach` (capital F) is a view builder expression, the body must create a view, in contrast to `forEach` (lowercase f) which is a convenience syntax for a standard `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you @vadian, it works not using `for`

Comment: You should use `first(where:)` or `firstIndex(where:)` instead of the loop to find the item.

Comment: Seems like you have already bound a property `clubName` for picker selection. You can use that directly to update distance, or better yet, use this object's distance property directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
func updateDistance() {

self.distance = clubLengths.map{$0.clubName == clubName}.first.distance

}
```

Try using `map` like I showed in above .